# Problem setting the location of the Facebook profile picture

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

What is the difference between the two?  Why can't I set it like a Binance profile?

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binance page is in classic mode.  And it will be retired soon